# ASP.NET Core 2.0 подсчет количества True строк в таблице с использованием Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть несколько таблиц (Тесты ,Вопросы тестов, ответы тестов (с колонкой IsCorrect где указано правильно ли ответил тестируемый), пользователи), для Asp.Net Core MVC 2.0 web приложения теста сотрудников с классом

```
public class PersonModel
        {
            [Key()]
            public Guid NameId { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string TestPackage { get; set; }

            public int Correct { get; set; }
        }
```

В последнем столбце идут bool значения (true или false), показывающий верный или нет был дан ответ.

При запросе

```
            var result = _context.Users
            .Join(_context.Answers, users => users.Id, answers => answers.UserId,
                (users, answers) => new {users, answers})
            .Join(_context.TestItems, @t => @t.answers.TestItemId, testItems => testItems.TestItemId,
                (@t, testItems) => new {@t, testItems})
            .Join(_context.TestPackages, @t => @t.testItems.TestPackageId,
                testPackages => testPackages.TestPackageId, (@t, testPackages) => new PersonModel()
                {
                    NameId = @t.@t.users.Id,
                    Name = @t.@t.users.UserName,
                    TestPackage = @t.@testItems.TestPackage.Name,
                    Correct = @t.@t.answers.IsCorrect
                });
```

я получаю Correct значение bool, но мне нужно что бы при нескольких ответах на несколько вопросов теста подсчитывался процент правильных ответов, вот так

```
Имя | Название теста | Процент правильности ответов
Вася  Test1            33 %
```

Проблема в том что этот запрос нужно отправить в grid, запрос должен давать ответ в IEnumerable три колонки (имя | название теста | процент правильных ответов)
Ответ так и не найден. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `int trueCount = result.Where(r => r.Correct == true).Count();`. Получаете количество ответов true. И потом находите сколько это процентов от общего количества

Comment: @WebMorda Не подходит вариант потому что нужно на выходе получить таблицу IEnumerable<PersonModel> с указанными столбцами